# Getting row number in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus

How do you get row number DataGridView cell? Specifically, if a user has selected a single cell, how can you get that row number? It needs to access a particular cell based on what the user has selected.

I know that the RemoveAt method can be used to remove at the Focus, but you cannot get the row number at focus apparently?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use [RowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex.aspx) on the [current cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx):

```
var row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 2):

this one works fine .

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint

If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also this code needs to be put in DataGridView1_CellContentClick event and you have to click in a cell. [code]  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

        Me.Label2.Text = e.RowIndex.ToString

    End Sub [/code]

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly the same but you may also use this solution:

```
var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you need to track user interaction with a DataGridView:
In my case there is extra processing in some generic functions that use the Me.I_SelCol and Me.I_SelRow column and row coordinates, but I haven't shown that because it's not relevant to the OP.

Best regards,
Rob

```
Private Sub I_DataGridView_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles I_DataGridView.CurrentCellChanged

        If Me.I_DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.X < 0 Or Me.I_DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y < 0 Then Exit Sub

        ' The Windows Me.I_DataGridView object will have already deselected the current cell and selected the 
        ' new cell as per user navigation using mouse or cursor keys.  We just need to store the current
        ' co-ordinates for the currently selected cell.

        Me.I_SelCol = Me.I_DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.X
        Me.I_SelRow = Me.I_DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y

Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you in event procedure of datagridview you will found "e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs" you can get row number with e.RowIndex and column number with e.ColumnIndex

```
Private Sub myDGV_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles myDGV.CellLeave
    Dim myRow As Integer = e.RowIndex
End Sub
```

And if you in normal procedure you can get row number like this:

```
Private Sub btnGetRow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetRow.Click
    dim myRow1 as Integer = 0
    dim myRow2 as Integer = 0
    myRow1 = myDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    myRow2 = myDGV.CurrentRow.Index
End Sub
```