# about datagrid in vb

Tags: vb.net

Please......any one can tell me code ....
how can i get a rownumber of a selected row from a DATAGRIDVIEW in VB.net forms.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting row number in a DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402944/getting-row-number-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: Damn, I voted to closed this by accident. >.< How can I unclose it? Sorry. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sort-of duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402944/getting-row-number-in-a-datagridview), answered by [Matt Hamilton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402944/getting-row-number-in-a-datagridview/1402970#1402970):

> You can simply use [RowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex.aspx) on the [current cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx):
>
> ```
> var row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
> ```